# the remote server machine is unavailable error '462'

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an excel userform a screen shot of which I would like to include in an outlook email. It works fine on my main programming computer, but when I run the same program on other computers I get the above error. The excel workbook is in the cloud and is run from the cloud (google drive) on various computers. the code is:

```vb
Function outlookEmail()
Dim doc As Object, rng As Range
    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .display
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
        .To = sDetail.Cells(myRow, headerDict.item("email"))
        .Subject = "documents for you"
    End With

End Function
```

the error is on the set doc line, if I mark it out, the error moves the the next line: doc.range...

Comment: Where and when do you run the VBA code? Is it on the server or service application?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a singleton. That means you can't run two instances of the application at the same time. If the Outlook Application is already running under the different security context you may get into troubles. So, I'd suggest checking whether Outlook is already running and make sure it is running under the same security context, so you could reach the instance.

You can use the Visual Basic `GetObject` function to return a reference to the `Application` object that represents a session that is already running. Note that because there can be only one instance of Outlook running at any given time, `GetObject` usually serves little purpose when used with Outlook. `CreateObject` can always be used to access the current instance of Outlook or to create a new instance if one does not exist. However, you can use error trapping with the `GetObject` method to determine whether Outlook is currently running.

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications) article.

Comment: The spreadsheet is saved in the cloud and might be accessed by several users at the same time, but each one is using his/hers own desktop